# ImageSpan height is less as compared to BackgroundColorSpan

Tags: android, spannablestring

I am using ImageSpan and BackgroundColorSpan for a string. I set the height of ImageSpan. 
Accorging to that BackgroundColorSpan auto adjust. But height of background of BackgroundColorSpan is little bit more as comapre to ImageSpan.

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

builder.append(a);

builder.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor(getResources()
                .getString(R.color.bg_keyword))), 1, 5, 0);

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(50, 30, Config.RGB_565);
builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(ctx, bitmap), 5, 10, 0);

builder.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor(getResources()
                .getString(R.color.bg_keyword))), 10, 15, 0);
tvSS.setText(builder);
```

Check also this screenshot:
[image: Any suggestion please]

Comment: did you try ImageSpan(Bitmap b, int verticalAlignment) ?

Comment: @pskink no. let me check this one

Comment: @pskink No it is not working. with ALIGN_BOTTOM, there is not change. I think this is default behavior of ImageSpan
with ALIGN_BASELINE, it is shifted up i.e. now there is blank white space below ImageSpan.

Comment: so it's all you can do...  what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to remove this white space.

Comment: you cannot,  unless you create a custom ImageSpan class, but the question is do you really need ImageSpan?

Comment: @pskink yes I need. Thanks for your suggestions. I will try for custom Image span class

Comment: maybe you can use DynamicDrawableSpan?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60223/discussion-between-ajit-and-pskink).